# docker in macOS running arm64 on amd64

Tags: linux, macos, docker, x86-64, arm64

While testing a specific version of the [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) project on a macOS (`version 10.13.6`), using `Docker 18.06.10-ce-mac73` I created this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends -q curl build-essential ca-certificates git net-tools netcat unzip jq
WORKDIR /vault
RUN mkdir -p /vault/bin && \
    cd /vault/bin && \
    curl -o vault.zip -sL https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/0.9.0/vault_0.9.0_linux_arm64.zip && unzip vault.zip
ENV PATH="/vault/bin:${PATH}"
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

The container came up, I was available to use it and run all the required tests, the only thing that I was noticing is that before the output of all the commands, I was getting something like this:

```
root@d2abe7afe964:/vault/bin# vault --version
Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 40
Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 41
Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 40
Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 41
Unknown QEMU_IFLA_INFO_KIND ipip
Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 40
Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 41
Unknown QEMU_IFLA_INFO_KIND ip6tnl
Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 40
Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 41
Vault v0.9.0 ('bdac1854478538052ba5b7ec9a9ec688d35a3335')
```

A colleague using a Linux(Ubuntu) couldn't run the `vault` command, the error he was getting was:

```
exec error command failed
```

After checking more in the detail the issue was that the Dockerfile was using [`vault_0.9.0_linux_arm64.zip`](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/0.9.0/vault_0.9.0_linux_arm64.zip) instead of [`vault_0.9.0_linux_amd64.zip`](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/0.9.0/vault_0.9.0_linux_amd64.zip). By mistake, the binary for the `arm64` was being used instead of the required `amd64` the thing that surprised us is that within the macOS environment was working.

Therefore would like to know more in detail why this happens, and if there is a way to run the containers in a "strict" or more Linux "like" when required?

Comment: You may interest yourself in `binfmt` and `qemu-arm-static`. Basically you can run a arm64 binary automagically via binfmt_musc to an emulator like qemu-arm-static and run it.

Answer (score 3):

Because the Docker on MacOS (your machine) comes with a Linux virtual machine (Docker container need some features of Linux kernel to run, so it cannot run on MacOS alone). That Linux VM has been configured with QEMU and binfmt_misc, so it can run the *arm64* container. Meanwhile, your friend machine has Docker running on his native Linux (not via VM), and his Linux is not configured enough to run *arm64* container.